# How to select rows using second condition if first condition doesn't match

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model `Post` and that has columns `text`, `point` and `created_at`.

To get first 3 posts that include text `foo` or `point` is more than `20`.

```
scope :foo_or_good_point, -> {
  where(<<-SQL)
    text LIKE '%foo%' OR point >= 20
  SQL
}
```

And if the row is not exists, use the recent 3 posts.

```
def self.foo_or_good_point_or_recent
  return foo_or_good_point.first(3) if foo_or_good_point.exists?
  order(created_at: :desc).first(3)
end
```

The code above works fine. But there are multiple SQL calls.
Can I write this behavior with a single SQL?

#### Environments

- PostgreSQL 9.6.3

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `PostgreSQL 9.6.3`. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to solve it using one SQL query like this

```
select *
from Post
where text LIKE '%foo%' OR point >= 20
  union all
select *
from Post
where not exists(select 1 from Post where text LIKE '%foo%' OR point >= 20) 
order by created_at desc
limit 3
```

Comment: @ironsand you are wellcome