# Postgres OR operator - Only check second condition if no match on first condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Is there a way to write an OR condition so that the second criteria is only checked if the first criteria yields no results?

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  column_a VARCHAR(10),
  column_b VARCHAR(10));
  
INSERT INTO some_table 
VALUES ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2');
```

I'd want this query to return only row with A1, B1, because it found a match using the first criteria:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table 
WHERE column_a = 'A1' OR column_b = 'B2';
```

I'd want this query to return only row with A2, B2, because there was no match on the first criteria:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table 
WHERE column_a = 'X1' OR column_b = 'B2';
```

Or perhaps there's a solution that doesnt use the OR operator?

I know you can execute multiple queries like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050267/how-to-select-rows-using-second-condition-if-first-condition-doesnt-match), but that's not ideal when the queries are much larger.

Another possible solution might be to use dynamic SQL, so you can store the majority of the query (without the second or criteria) as a variable execute it, and if no results, append the OR criteria and execute it again. This would prevent duplication of code in larger queries, but I'm sure there *must* be a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> write an OR condition so that the second criteria is only checked if the first criteria yields no results

The `where` predicate clause is correctly phrased with `OR`. If you want just one row in the resultset, we can `order by` a conditional expression that puts first rows that match the first condition, then `limit`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE column_a = 'A1' OR column_b = 'B2'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_a = 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
LIMIT 1
```

---

If there might be *several* rows matching on a given criteria, then you might want to add another column to the `ORDER BY` clause to make the sort predictable, say primary key column `id`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_a = 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, id
LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively, if you want to retain all rows that match the given criteria, then you use window functions and `fetch` instead:

```
ORDER BY RANK() OVER(ORDER BY BY CASE WHEN column_a = 'A1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. The third seems like such a great solution and does exactly what I need it to. I would have never found this on my own, but now that I know of it, I expect this wont be the only time I use it. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to add for future readers, the [`WITH TIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) syntax is only available from v13 (sadly this caught me out).